# Strange Logcat message while running a Device with Android 5 and cannot save captured image on CameraX

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas

So I have a CameraX App that I can extract a Photo with Bitmap and Exif Interface, everything works on a different physical device such as Android 9. So the issue I am having is from an other device that the version of Android 5 (API Level 21) and having weird messages in Logcat while the app is running, the other device didn't actually show up on that and it has something to do with Color or Canvas, I really don't know what it means, just wanna ask about this message what it means and does it has something occurring to my main problem:

```
D/ColorDrawable: Color = -1, canvas = android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas@22143b55, mTintMode = SRC_IN, mTint = null, ColorDrawable = android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@1832f151
```

The other message I believe is the permissions request issue, since it displays this error message, maybe I am wrong, but I won't deny any help with it as a sign:

```
E/MainActivity: Photo capture failed: Failed to rename file.
```

The full report in the Logcat:

```
D/ColorDrawable: Color = -1, canvas = android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas@22143b55, mTintMode = SRC_IN, mTint = null, ColorDrawable = android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@1832f151
E/MainActivity: Photo capture failed: Failed to rename file.
    androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureException: Failed to rename file.
        at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture$2.onError(ImageCapture.java:912)
        at androidx.camera.core.ImageSaver.lambda$postError$2$ImageSaver(ImageSaver.java:306)
        at androidx.camera.core.ImageSaver$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5534)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
D/ColorDrawable: Color = -1, canvas = android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas@22143b55, mTintMode = SRC_IN, mTint = null, ColorDrawable = android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@1832f151
D/ColorDrawable: Color = -1, canvas = android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas@22143b55, mTintMode = SRC_IN, mTint = null, ColorDrawable = android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@1832f151
D/ColorDrawable: Color = -1, canvas = android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas@22143b55, mTintMode = SRC_IN, mTint = null, ColorDrawable = android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@1832f151
D/ColorDrawable: Color = -1, canvas = android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas@22143b55, mTintMode = SRC_IN, mTint = null, ColorDrawable = android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@1832f151
I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-12012-6](this:0x7f814de000,id:6,api:4,p:247,c:12012) queueBuffer: fps=1.93 dur=1036.95 max=540.20 min=496.75
I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-12012-6](this:0x7f814de000,id:6,api:4,p:247,c:12012) new GraphicBuffer needed
D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x7f8223e3e0) (w:4224 h:3136 s:4224 f:0x32315659 u:0x000102)
I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-12012-5](this:0x7f7308c000,id:5,api:1,p:12012,c:12012) queueBuffer: fps=8.31 dur=2045.02 max=1311.34 min=36.17
D/ColorDrawable: Color = -1, canvas = android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas@22143b55, mTintMode = SRC_IN, mTint = null, ColorDrawable = android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@1832f151
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7f8553a7a0) (w:4224 h:3136 s:4224 f:0x32315659 u:0x000102)
D/ColorDrawable: Color = -1, canvas = android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas@22143b55, mTintMode = SRC_IN, mTint = null, ColorDrawable = android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@1832f151
I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-12012-6](this:0x7f814de000,id:6,api:4,p:247,c:12012) new GraphicBuffer needed
D/ColorDrawable: Color = -1, canvas = android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas@22143b55, mTintMode = SRC_IN, mTint = null, ColorDrawable = android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@1832f151
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7f8553a840) (w:4224 h:3136 s:4224 f:0x32315659 u:0x000102)
```

this is the Manifest at this moment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.testCameraX">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the "MyLocation" functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" /> <!-- Needed only if your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher. -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" /> <!--For SD cards-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_cadis_dark_foreground"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_cadis_dark_foreground"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CadisMap2">
        <activity android:name=".activities.PreviewPhoto" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.CameraActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LocationInfoActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MapsActivity" />
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm displaying the full code of the `onImageSaved()`, just to let everyone who reads this. It runs with minimum SDK of "21" (`minSdkVersion 21`) in Gradle:

```
private var outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()

/**Getting output directory method to save to external file image folder**/
    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull().let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
        return if (mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
    }

private fun takePhoto() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Обработва се ..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        // Create time-stamped output file to hold the image
        val photoFile = File(
            outputDirectory,
            SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")

        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    //PreviewView that we include it with a variable for Bitmap
                    val previewView = findViewById<PreviewView>(R.id.viewFinder)

                    //Views for the GPS string watermarks
                    val errorMessage = "Error!"
                    val apiError = "None"
                    val longitudeWM = resources.getString(R.string.value_format_7, mLocation?.longitude)
                    val latitudeWM = resources.getString(R.string.value_format_7, mLocation?.latitude)
                    val altitudeWM = resources.getString(R.string.value_format_2, mLocation?.altitude)
                    val hozAccuracyWM = resources.getString(R.string.value_format_2, mLocation?.accuracy)

                    //This is placed like this if the vertical accuracy does not meet below the API level of Android 26
                    val verAccuracyWM: String = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 26) {
                        if (mLocation!!.hasVerticalAccuracy()) {
                            resources.getString(R.string.value_format_2, mLocation!!.verticalAccuracyMeters)
                        } else {
                            errorMessage
                        }
                    } else {
                        apiError
                    }

                    //The orientation windowManager provides which orientation is our device
                    var orientationWM: String
                    val windowOrientation = windowManager.defaultDisplay.orientation
                    orientationWM = windowOrientation.toString()

                    when (windowOrientation) {
                        0 -> orientationWM = "Portrait"
                        1 -> orientationWM = "Landscape"
                        2 -> orientationWM = "Reverse Portrait"
                        3 -> orientationWM = "Reverse Landscape"
                    }

                    //Azimuth, Pitch and Roll
                    fun onResume() {
                        mSensorManager.registerListener(
                            this@CameraActivity,
                            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
                            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME
                        )
                    }

                    fun onPause() {
                        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this@CameraActivity)
                    }

                    onResume()
                    onPause()
                    val azimuthWMText = resources.getString(R.string.value_format_2, mSensorEvent?.values?.get(0))
                    val pitchWMText = resources.getString(R.string.value_format_2, mSensorEvent?.values?.get(1))
                    val rollWMText = resources.getString(R.string.value_format_2, mSensorEvent?.values?.get(2))

                    //Bitmap that contains the addWatermark method and detecting the new photo path that is been taken and implements the watermark
                    //BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path.toString(), BitmapFactory.Options())
                    //resources, R.layout.activity_preview_photo, BitmapFactory.Options()
                    val originalBitmap = AddWatermark().addWatermark(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.toString(), BitmapFactory.Options()),
                        firstWatermarkText = "Longitude: $longitudeWM${resources.getString(R.string.degrees)}, Latitude: $latitudeWM${resources.getString(R.string.degrees)}",
                        secondWatermarkText = "Altitude: ${altitudeWM}м, Ориентация: $orientationWM",
                        thirdWatermarkText = "Accuracy: Horizontal: ${hozAccuracyWM}м, Vertical: ${verAccuracyWM}м",
                        fourthWatermarkText = "Direction: where $azimuthWMText${resources.getString(R.string.degrees)}",
                        fifthWatermarkText = "Tilting: pitchTilt $pitchWMText${resources.getString(R.string.degrees)}, rollTilt $rollWMText${resources.getString(R.string.degrees)}",
                        AddWatermark.WatermarkOptions(
                            AddWatermark.Corner.TOP_LEFT,
                            textSizeToWidthRation = 0.017f,
                            paddingToWidthRatio = 0.03f,
                            Color.parseColor("#FF0000"),
                            shadowColor = Color.BLACK,
                            strokeOutline = null,
                            typeface = null
                        )
                    )
                    previewView.bitmap.let { originalBitmap }

                    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(photoFile)
                    originalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outputStream)
                    outputStream.flush()
                    outputStream.close()
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@CameraActivity,
                        "Capture success!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()

                    //Exif interface
                    val exif = ExifInterface(photoFile)
                    checkExifData(exif)
                }
            })
    }

    private fun checkExifData(exifInterface: ExifInterface) {
        saveExifData(exifInterface) // This method will save any custom/changed data in it and will re-use the tag as an identifier.
        val exifModel = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL)
        val exifManufacturer = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_CAMERA_OWNER_NAME)
        val exifFlash = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH)
        val exifArtist = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ARTIST)
        val exifDateTime = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME)
        val exifLatitude = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE)
        val exifLatitudeRef = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF)
        val exifLongitude = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE)
        val exifLongitudeRef = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF)

        //Displaying in the Logcat and Debugger, making sure it saved and reads the right data.
        Log.i("Model", "$exifModel")
        Log.i("Manufacturer", "$exifManufacturer")
        Log.i("Flash Mode", "$exifFlash")
        Log.i("Artist", "$exifArtist")
        Log.i("Date Time", "$exifDateTime")
        Log.i("Latitude", "$exifLatitude")
        Log.i("Latitude Reference", "$exifLatitudeRef")
        Log.i("Longitude", "$exifLongitude")
        Log.i("Longitude Reference", "$exifLongitudeRef")
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private fun saveExifData(exifInterface: ExifInterface) {
        try {
            //Model
            val model = Build.MODEL.toString()
            exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL, model)

            //Manufacturer
            val manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER
            exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_CAMERA_OWNER_NAME, manufacturer)

            //Artist
            val artist = "Test"
            exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ARTIST, artist)

            //Date Time
            val simpleDateTime = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss").format(System.currentTimeMillis())
            exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, simpleDateTime)

            val longitude = resources.getString(R.string.value_format_7, mLocation?.longitude)
            val latitude = resources.getString(R.string.value_format_7, mLocation?.latitude)
            Log.e("Longitude", longitude)
            Log.e("Latitude", latitude)

            //Full display of the calculation of the Latitude's and Longitude's degrees, minutes and seconds.
            exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, latitude)
            exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, longitude)

            //This if statement will provide information of the latitude and longitude reference letter.
            if (latitude > 0.toString()) {
                exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "N")
            } else {
                exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "S")
            }

            if (longitude > 0.toString()) {
                exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "E")
            } else {
                exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "W")
            }
            exifInterface.setGpsInfo(mLocation)

            exifInterface.saveAttributes()//This will save any written data that the tags are included.
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e("Error", "Exif is corrupted and didn't saved!")
        }
    }
```

This is the seperated class for `AddWatermark()` bitmap:

```
class AddWatermark {
    //Adding watermark method is here for declaring on to the top
    fun addWatermark(bitmap: Bitmap, firstWatermarkText: String, secondWatermarkText: String, thirdWatermarkText: String, fourthWatermarkText: String, fifthWatermarkText: String, options: WatermarkOptions = WatermarkOptions()): Bitmap {
        val result = bitmap.copy(bitmap.config, true)
        val canvas = Canvas(result)
        val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG or Paint.DITHER_FLAG)
        //val strokePaint = Paint()

        //We are including the Enum class and connecting with the data class WatermarkOptions variable
        paint.textAlign = when (options.corner) {
            //We include the alignment LEFT from Enum class and connecting with Paint variable
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT -> Paint.Align.LEFT

            //We include the alignment RIGHT from Enum class and connecting with Paint variable
            Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> Paint.Align.RIGHT
        }

        /*strokePaint.textAlign = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT -> Paint.Align.LEFT

            Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> Paint.Align.RIGHT
        }

         */

        //We connect the new textSize variable with the bitmap width(default is 0) and we multiply with the WatermarkOption's textSize
        val textSize = result.width * options.textSizeToWidthRation
        //Connecting the Paint textSize variable with the new textSize variable
        paint.textSize = textSize//70.5f
        //Connecting the Paint color variable with the WatermarkOptions textColor
        paint.color = options.textColor
        //If the shadowColor of the WMOptions is not null, then we make it as a Paint shadowLayer variable
        if (options.shadowColor != null) {
            paint.setShadowLayer( 2.5f, 0f, 0f, options.shadowColor)
        }

        /*if (options.strokeOutline != null) {
            strokePaint.textSize = textSize//72f
            strokePaint.color = options.strokeOutline
            strokePaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            strokePaint.strokeWidth = 4.17f
        }

         */

        //If typeface of the WMOptions is not null,we make paint typeface variable and connecting with the WMOptions variable
        if (options.typeface != null) {
            paint.typeface = options.typeface
        }
        //We connect the new padding variable with the bitmap width(default is 0) and multiply with WMOptions padding
        val padding = result.width * options.paddingToWidthRatio

        //Create a variable that has something to do with the coordinates method
        val coordinates = calculateCoordinates(firstWatermarkText, secondWatermarkText, thirdWatermarkText, fourthWatermarkText, fifthWatermarkText, paint, options, canvas.width, canvas.height, padding)
        /**drawText text and stroke**/
        //canvas.drawText(firstWatermarkText, coordinates.x, coordinates.y, strokePaint)
        canvas.drawText(firstWatermarkText, coordinates.x, coordinates.y, paint)

        //canvas.drawText(secondWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 240f, strokePaint) //We change the Y horizontal coordinates by typing the float number
        canvas.drawText(secondWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 240f, paint)

        //canvas.drawText(thirdWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 310f, strokePaint)
        canvas.drawText(thirdWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 310f, paint)

        //canvas.drawText(fourthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 380f, strokePaint)
        canvas.drawText(fourthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 380f, paint)

        //canvas.drawText(fifthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 450f, strokePaint)
        canvas.drawText(fifthWatermarkText, coordinates.x, 450f, paint)

        return result
    }

    //This it he corner alignment calculation method and using it on the drawText
    private fun calculateCoordinates(
        firstWatermarkText: String,
        secondWatermarkText: String,
        thirdWatermarkText: String,
        fourthWatermarkText: String,
        fifthWatermarkText: String,
        paint: Paint,
        options: WatermarkOptions,
        width: Int,
        height: Int,
        padding: Float
    ): PointF {
        val x = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT -> {
                padding
            }
            Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> {
                width - padding
            }
        }

        val y = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> {
                height - padding
            }
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
            Corner.TOP_RIGHT -> {
                val bounds = Rect()

                paint.getTextBounds(firstWatermarkText, 0, firstWatermarkText.length, bounds)
                paint.getTextBounds(secondWatermarkText, 0, secondWatermarkText.length, bounds)
                paint.getTextBounds(thirdWatermarkText, 0, thirdWatermarkText.length, bounds)
                paint.getTextBounds(fourthWatermarkText, 0, fourthWatermarkText.length, bounds)
                paint.getTextBounds(fifthWatermarkText, 0, fifthWatermarkText.length, bounds)

                val textHeight = bounds.height()
                textHeight + padding
            }
        }
        return PointF(x, y)
    }

    enum class Corner {
        TOP_LEFT,
        TOP_RIGHT,
        BOTTOM_LEFT,
        BOTTOM_RIGHT
    }

    data class WatermarkOptions(
        val corner: Corner = Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        val textSizeToWidthRation: Float = 0.04f,
        val paddingToWidthRatio: Float = 0.03f,
        @ColorInt val textColor: Int = Color.parseColor("#FFC800"),
        @ColorInt val shadowColor: Int? = Color.BLACK,
        @ColorInt val strokeOutline: Int? = Color.BLACK,
        val typeface: Typeface? = null
    )
}
```

Comment: And what is a `photoFile`?

Comment: The photoFile is the File type variable that it makes the name, also the file type is JPEG image file.